# Can The phone collections of a Contact in Outlook REST API allow more than 2 records?

Tags: outlook, office365-apps

I worked on an application that uses the Outlook REST API to retrieve contact information and my team realized that the phone collections of the contact (BusinessPhones and HomePhones) only allow 2 records. If it send a third value in one of the collections, the API return an error explaining that it cannot do this.

Is there something it can be done to work with more values in these collections?

Answer (score 0):

You get a lot more than that.

```
AssistantTelephoneNumber, BusinessTelephoneNumbe, 
Business2TelephoneNumber, CallbackTelephoneNumber, 
CarTelephoneNumber, CompanyMainTelephoneNumber, 
Home2TelephoneNumber, HomeTelephoneNumber, 
MobileTelephoneNumber, OtherTelephoneNumber, 
PrimaryTelephoneNumber, RadioTelephoneNumber, 
TTYTDDTelephoneNumber
```

"The API return an error explaining that it cannot do this."? What API? What is the exact error?

Comment: This Outlook API: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations#Getcontacts

When it try to post a contact with a HomePhone collection with more than 2 values for example, is returned the message: "The multi value property HomePhones has 3 entries, that exceeds the max allowed value of 2."

Comment: Sorry, don't know about the Rest API. I meant the Outlook Object Model.